# Proper NginX loadbalance settings

Tags: nginx

I have 1 NginX Loadbalancer with the following config:

```
upstream websiteloaded  {
        server mywebsite2.mycompany.hu;
        server mywebsite3.mycompany.hu backup;
}

    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name mywebsite.mycompany.hu;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass      http://websiteloaded;
                    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            }
    }

    server {
            listen 443;
            server_name mywebsite.mycompany.hu;

            ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/mycompany.hu.combined.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/mycompany.hu.key;

            ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
            ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
            add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
            ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass      https://mywebsite;
                    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            }
    }
```

On each of the mywebsite2 and 3 serving servers I have NginX config like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name     www.mywebsite2.mycompany.hu mywebsite2.mycompany.hu;

        return 301      https://mywebsite2.mycompany.hu$request_uri;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/hu.mywebsite2/access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/hu.mywebsite2/error.log;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name     www.mywebsite2.mycompany.hu;

        return 301      https://mywebsite2.mycompany.hu$request_uri;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/hu.mywebsite2/access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/hu.mywebsite2/error.log;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/mycompany.hu.combined.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/mycompany.hu.key;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name     mywebsite2.mycompany.hu mywebsite.mycompany.hu;
        root            /var/www/html/hu.mywebsite2/public;

        error_log       /var/log/nginx/hu.mywebsite2/error.log;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/hu.mywebsite2/access.log;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mycompany.hu.combined.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/mycompany.hu.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;

        index index.php;

        rewrite ^/index\.php?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

        location / {
                try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }

        location @rewrite {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
        }

        location ~ ^/index.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/nginx.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

Now the redirect is fine. My question is: Why is the URL changeing from mywebsite.mycompany.hu to mywebsite2.mycompany.hu ?

Answer (score 0):

In the destination configs you are always forcefully 301 redirect to the proxy hostname, that way, while the proxy_pass and set_header directive of the load balancer are probabily working, they are *overwritten* by the "return"

> return 301      https://mywebsite2.mycompany.hu$request_uri;

It depends on your needings but I don't think that you need that much configuration on backends. If you need just the ssl version as final destination it would be better to 301 redirect to https on the balancer server and then a simple proxy_pass to the https configuration.

Something like

*first server*

```
server {
        server_name mywebsite.mycompany.hu;
        return 301 https://mywebsite.mycompany.hu.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443;
        server_name mywebsite.mycompany.hu;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/mycompany.hu.combined.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/mycompany.hu.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;

        location / {
                proxy_pass      https://websiteloaded;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        }
}
```

*backend server*

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name     mywebsite2.mycompany.hu mywebsite.mycompany.hu;
    root            /var/www/html/hu.mywebsite2/public;

    error_log       /var/log/nginx/hu.mywebsite2/error.log;
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/hu.mywebsite2/access.log;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mycompany.hu.combined.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/mycompany.hu.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;

    index index.php;

    rewrite ^/index\.php?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    location / {
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/index.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/nginx.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable and it is working. However, I still get redirected to the mywebsite2.mycompany.hu instead of staying on mywebsite.mycompany.hu What could be the reason behind this? Because of this redirection, the loadbalance doesn't work since the URL get's rewrittem constantly to the main server, even when it is turned off. Oh, and can you please remove the `hams2` from your post and replace it with `mywebsite2` ? My boss would kill me if he sees it. :)

Comment: Just to be sure, have you pointed the dns entry (A or CNAME) to the fist server only? (ps. edited as requested)

Comment: I've used A record for all 3 domain names. Now I get a constant too many files open error message and from the logs, I can see that the same file is being called over and over for a few hundred times.

Comment: It's the backend server that is calling back the primary ? Can you provide some extra log?

Comment: Well, I'm ashamed a bit because there was a type error in my code. Now I'm getting closer, but still getting errors. Now it is SSL handshake. Logs are in the URL [link]https://pastebin.com/iDhh5z44

Comment: WORKS? WORKS? WORKS! Posting the solution in a minute. Soo annoying issue, not even the documentation mentiones it, I've just tried something and it work. 1 min

Answer (score 0):

The log line led me to the solution is the following:

```
2017/06/20 10:16:21 [error] 11345#11345: *1 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 37.220.XXX.XXX, server: mywebsite.mycompany.hu, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://217.112.XXX.XXX:80/", host: "mywebsite.mycompany.hu"
```

Notice the `upstream: "https://217.112.XXX.XXX:80/", host: "mywebsite.mycompany.hu"` at the end. This is all wrong since the mywebsite.mycompany.hu is reachable only on 443, not 80. Now where do I have to set up the loadbalancer to try 443 instead of 80. Solution is here:

```
upstream websiteloaded  {
        server mywebsite2.mycompany.hu;
        server mywebsite3.mycompany.hu backup;
}
```

I've put this to the nginx.conf instead of the custom config, tho it doesn't matter. what matter is that the URL needs 443 to the end!

```
upstream websiteloaded  {
        server mywebsite2.mycompany.hu:443;
        server mywebsite3.mycompany.hu:443 backup;
}
```

And miracle, it works. Now I don't want to be upset, but I haven't found this anywhere in NginX documentation. I hope I just missed it and it was all my fault. Otherwise I blame the dev. team for not making a correct users manual. Anyhow thanks for the help!

Comment: Have a look into the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server): "The address can be specified as a domain name or IP address, with an optional port [...]".